# Is it safe to use the same keystore in multiple hosts via tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, keystore, keytool

I created a self-signed keystore using java keytools and i'm wondering if its ok to use the same keystore in multiple hosts.  Are there any pros and cons?  How about if the keystore has a domain name for "First name and Last name", does that change anything if the keystore is used in multiple hosts?

Also generally, when creating new hosts, should a new self-signed cert be created for each one?

Comment: A keystore is just a container of some keys. It really depends on how you use these keys.

Comment: A certificate uniquely identifies a host, including its FQDN. It doesn't make the least bit of sense to use one certificate for multiple hosts, and they will fail HTTPS hostname validation at the clients. Using self-signed certificates doesn't make the least bit of sense either.

Comment: By hosts do you mean _TLS servers_ and possibly _HTTPS servers_ liike Tomcat? Java crypto and certs can be used for other things. Are these servers used from/on the Internet or only local or restricted? @EJP: for a public server, cert CommonName must be FQDN _or_ a matching wildcard name _unless_ you use SubjectAlternativeName which can have _many_ hostnames and is supported by `keytool` since Java7 (2011). That said, selfsigned takes $0 and <1min, so you might as well do as many of them as you want.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, @EJP :  This is for a private network, so we would only be running https on our local intranet and not over the internet.